# SVN - Trying to delete a file from my repo that i imported in the wrong place

Tags: svn

I accidently imported a file into the wrong place in my repo. Now i want to delete it from my repo.

I tried using:

```
svn delete https://mysubdomain.svn.beanstalkapp.com/repo/trunk/badfile
```

but when i do that, I get a screen that looks like this

```
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--

D    https://mysubdomain.svn.beanstalkapp.com/repo/trunk/badfile

----:---F1  svn-commit.8.tmp   All L1     (Fundamental)---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loading vc...done
```

I'm completely lost once i hit this screen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the repo since you did the delete? Based on what you posted, it looks like the delete was successful.

Comment: Yep. It's definitely still in the repo. The screen that i get is like interactive. I'm not sure if it's some sort of editor that i've never used or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there's no error. You just need to input a log message, save and quit.

You can do two things:

- Find a VIM tutorial [(one here)](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/vim_tutorial.html). VIM is the text editor launched by defaults by SVN when you need to enter a commit message.
- Change your `SVN_EDITOR` environment variable to something you are more familiar with. [Here](http://www.techchorus.net/how-set-svneditor-environment-variable-vim) is a small how-to though it sets it to VIM which you are likely not to want.

Comment: Good call. I wasn't aware that it was using VIM. I changed my default to pico.